# How detect different colors

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am learning Image Filtering using opencv. I wrote some code but my code could only detect objects with red color, How can I detect objects with other colors.

I tried different numpy array values, still I'm not satisfied with output

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue = np.array([150,150,0])
upper_blue = np.array([255,255,225])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue,upper_blue)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
```

Comment: You would need to change `lower` and `upper` values for various colors, which color you want to segment? And what are the values that you have tried for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the boundary values (in your case lower_blue and upper_blue) to different values. The values may range ass follows [0 < H< 179], [0 < S < 255], [0 < V < 255]. You can see it better from the picture.

Good luck!

[image: HSV values]

Answer (score 0):

First, the range of H should be from 0 to 179. To get the feeling of what combination of  HSV values produces what color here is a small piece of code. Below code creates trackbars for H, S, V. Adjust the trackbars to segment the different colors.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)


# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('lowH','image',0,179,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('highH','image',179,179,nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('lowS','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('highS','image',255,255,nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('lowV','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('highV','image',255,255,nothing)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # get current positions of the trackbars
    ilowH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lowH', 'image')
    ihighH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('highH', 'image')
    ilowS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lowS', 'image')
    ihighS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('highS', 'image')
    ilowV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lowV', 'image')
    ihighV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('highV', 'image')

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_hsv = np.array([ilowH, ilowS, ilowV])
    higher_hsv = np.array([ihighH, ihighS, ihighV])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, higher_hsv)

    frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
    cv2.imshow('image', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```